# Detect and query specific languages

Tags: php, mysql, localization

I have data in different languages inserted into my db, such as chinese, french, english, malay, japanese, korean, etc.

How can I detect those languages and query the specific one. For example if I only want to query data in chinese and display it to users.

Comment: What does your database look like? Or have you not designed it yet?

Comment: Already have the db and using UTF8 and able to insert using different languages. But i want to have a features like English, Chinese, Japanese buttons so if users click on them will only display specify languages.

Comment: Make each language a different table in the database(?)... Or provide more information about your database setup

Comment: I would *not* make a different table for each language, as that is very inflexible. You would have to change the SQL in your DB query every time the user switched languages.

Comment: Yes, each languages a different table is bad idea. What happen if i have 50 different langauges?  =.=

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I were you, I'd have something like this to store the text that is displayed in your UI controls:

```sql
create table ui_labels (
  control_id int,
  language varchar(2),
  label varchar(500),
  primary key (control_id, language)
);
```

There will be one unique `control_id` for each control (e.g. button) in your UI. Each control can have many labels, one for each language.

Then, each UI control can have a different label for each language. (I'm assuming a two-letter ISO language code here, but you could also use a numeric ID or some other identification scheme.)

This makes it easy to add new languages just by adding rows to the `ui_labels` table, and easy to switch the language displayed in the UI just by switching the `language` value that you use in your queries.

The data for a button could look like this:

```sql
insert into ui_labels (control_id, language, label)
  values (1, 'en', 'Read the article');
insert into ui_labels (control_id, language, label)
  values (1, 'es', 'Leer el artículo');
insert into ui_labels (control_id, language, label)
  values (1, 'tl', 'Bumasa ang balita');
```

As an alternative to this approach, though, you may want to look into [gettext](http://php.net/manual/en/book.gettext.php), which is a standard way to do translation in PHP. It doesn't use your database. If it's a requirement to put the strings in the database (for example, if an end-user has to be able to edit them), then this isn't an option, but it may be something that you can consider. If you are interested in this, you might want to have a look at this blog post:

http://verens.com/2008/04/03/translation-in-php/

Comment: If i have the control_id = 1 is English and control_id = 2 is Malay How do i detect the user input language and insert with the control_id? Since English and Malay use the same Alphabet ( A-Z ).

Use Google translate api ?

Comment: You need to inspect the HTTP request and see what language the user wants to use. The page that I linked to in my answer mentions how to do this. Look for the part where it says: "Next, parse the browser’s Accept header for a locale which matches what we have."

Comment: Also, you will not have a different control_id for the different languages. The button has the same control_id, but there are different rows for that button that contain translations in different languages. I've added an example to show what I mean.